# Is it possible to have one polybar (or any other i3bar) on top and one other on the bottom of the same screen?

Tags: i3, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using Polybar 3.4.0 and I would like to know if it was possible to put one bar at the top of the screen and another one at the bottom.

I would like to display a lot of information at the same time, but my bar isn't large enough.

If someone knows a better alternative to polybar to perform this, you suggestions are welcome.

I'm using i3-wm 4.18.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

You have to create multiple bars and position one of them at the top and the other at the bottom.
In the [bar section](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Configuration#bar-settings) for each bar, there is a `bottom` setting. So for one bar you would set `bottom = true` and for the other `bottom = false`. This could look something like this:

```dosini
[bar/top]
bottom = false
modules-left = ...

...

[bar/bottom]
bottom = true
modules-left = ...

...
```

You then also have to run both bars:

```sh
polybar ... top &
polybar ... bottom &
```

This is not a complete code example, you will still need to fill out the rest of the bar section and add some modules.

---

A quick note about terminology. You are asking about "polybar (or some other i3bar)". But those things are not the same. i3bar is a specific status bar that comes with i3, it can display content from various sources (e.g. i3status, i3blocks). polybar is another status bar and not related to i3bar.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for. And thank you for your explanations about the status bar. I did ignore that.